# Cant open corrupted .cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So my computer crashed while Visual Studio 2012 was on and my .cs file got corrupted. In Notepad++ there are just many 'NUL' words in black font and in simple notepad just white spaces, file had taken up some memory so I think its not all gone. I tried to recover it with Recuva, but after that file has a lot of random symbols screenshot:
[image: Corrupted file]
So should I start coding over or I have a chance of saving it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. The recovered file is in a different location so I do have the original corrupted file.[Corrupted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aHNB.png)

Comment: thats not a cs file - cs is pure text only.....

Comment: Sorry, what I have in mind is a Class type file.

Comment: ALL source code files are pure text.. so a class is also pure text, as is the form designer source..

Comment: Deleted asp.net tag - I doubt the content has anything to do with it. Bad tag.

Comment: Happens sometimes. Do you have source control? Or putting the file/filesystem back in time?

Comment: If you can't recover the file using a tool for this purpose, you *might* be able to decompile your assembly using `dotPeek` or similar tools and get back at least something that resembles the code you had. If that is not working out either you are left with restarting. Oh, and you should start using version control, then at least you would only lose the *latest changes* and not *everything*.

Comment: I wanted to try dotPeek, but I cant find .dll file of my project. It's a web app and I cant find it nowhere in project folder.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me a few times as well when VS crashed. In some of the cases, the files couldn't be recovered at all, but sometimes I managed to recover them using [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva). You can find a tutorial [here](http://data-security-freeware.blogspot.ro/2011/04/recuva-recover-deleted-files-for-free.html).

Comment: OP already mentions having used recuva

Answer (score 0):

So I tried Recuva again but this time I looked in all shadow copies. I got few versions of my file and it seems not to miss any info needed. I thank everyone who contributed.